# wget is fast, but php file() function is too slow

Tags: performance, file

```
wget "http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/product/index.jsp?productId=45866296" -O d.html
```

is very fast. about 1 sec.

but `file()` php function is too slow, it takes about 10 sec.

I don't use bind. just use ISP name server.

When I try `nslookup dickssportinggoods.com` it takes just 1 sec or less.

My os is centos 5.x.

I don't know what is wrong...

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need?

Comment: For me `<?php $arr = file("http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/product/index.jsp?productId=45866296"); ?>` works just as fast as `wget`. Show your code.